# MongoDB $substr equality issue

Tags: mongodb

```
{      
  "val1" : "abcdefghijk",
  "val2" : "abcdefzzzzz"
}
```

When performing `$eq` on computed sub-strings in an aggregate, the behaviour does not seem to work as expected. The document above is returned with `{ subMatch : true }` even though `"abcdefg" != "abcdefz"`.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
  {"$project": {
    "val1":1,
    "val2":1,
    "val1Sub": { "$substr" : [ "$val1", 0, 7 ] },
    "val2Sub": { "$substr": [ "$val2", 0, 7] },
    "subMatch": { "$eq":["$val1Sub","$val2Sub"] }
    }
  },
  {"$match":{"subMatch": true}}
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val1Sub` and `val2Sub` both are equally not defined **at this stage**. The are defined only **after the stage**.

You can either add a second `$project` stage to calculate `subMatch`:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
  {"$project": {
    "val1":1,
    "val2":1,
    "val1Sub": { "$substr" : [ "$val1", 0, 7 ] },
    "val2Sub": { "$substr": [ "$val2", 0, 7] }
    }
  },
  {"$project": {
    "subMatch": { "$eq":["$val1Sub","$val2Sub"] }
  },
  {"$match":{"subMatch": true}}
])
```

or inline `$substr`s:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
  {"$project": {
    "val1":1,
    "val2":1,
    "val1Sub": { "$substr" : [ "$val1", 0, 7 ] },
    "val2Sub": { "$substr": [ "$val2", 0, 7] },
    "subMatch": { "$eq":[
        { "$substr" : [ "$val1", 0, 7 ] },
        { "$substr": [ "$val2", 0, 7] }
    ] }
    }
  },
  {"$match":{"subMatch": true}}
])
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I had a feeling it was something along these lines.

Comment: May I suggest you use `$addFields` instead of `$project` to remove the `val1: 1` and `val2: 1` bits?

Comment: @dnickless, of course, your answer is way better for real life use. I just explained mechanics why OP get confusing results.

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case where the [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) operator can help to express things in a concise fashion:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        result: {
            $let: {
                vars: {
                    "val1SubVariable": { "$substr" : [ "$val1", 0, 7 ] },
                    "val2SubVariable": { "$substr" : [ "$val2", 0, 7 ] }
                },
                in: {
                    "val1Sub": "$$val1SubVariable",
                    "val2Sub": "$$val2SubVariable",
                    "subMatch": { "$eq": [ "$$val1SubVariable", "$$val2SubVariable" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: { "result.subMatch": true }
}])
```

Also note that from MongoDB v3.6 the $project/$addFields stage isn't needed at all if all you want to do is filter. Check out the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) based version below:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $expr: {
            $eq: [
                { "$substr" : [ "$val1", 0, 7 ] },
                { "$substr" : [ "$val2", 0, 7 ] }
            ]
        }
    }
}])
```